# Apply z-index to all divs starting from the highest

Tags: javascript

I have this simple loop which adds `z-index` to an element in the DOM.

```js
let init = () => {
  let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".pa");
  let initialIndex = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    allDivs[i].style.zIndex = initialIndex++
  }
}
init();
```

```html
<div class="ma">
   <div class="pa">Test</div>
   <div class="pa">Test</div>
   <div class="pa">Test</div>
</div>
```

Then, in turn, all my `.pa` divs do get the index applied and increment by one.

The problem is, I need to go the other way. To start at the highest, whether that be 3, 5 or 10 and then work backwards.

---

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
<div class="pa" style="z-index: 1;"></div>
<div class="pa" style="z-index: 2;"></div>
<div class="pa" style="z-index: 3;"></div>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
<div class="pa" style="z-index: 3;"></div>
<div class="pa" style="z-index: 2;"></div>
<div class="pa" style="z-index: 1;"></div>
```

---

I did try using `--` so it would read `allDivs[i].style.zIndex = initialIndex--` but this just took the z-index down 1,0,-1.

Likely a super dumb question but I can't figure out how I would do this?

Comment: Post the actual code that is **not** working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse the array reverse

```js
let init = () => {
  let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".pa");

  let initialIndex = 1;

  for (let i = allDivs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    allDivs[i].style.zIndex = initialIndex++
  }
}
init();
```

```html
<div class="ma">
  <div class="pa">Test</div>
  <div class="pa">Test</div>
  <div class="pa">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start the `initialIndex` with the array's length then decrements by each loop.

```js
let init = () => {
  let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".pa");
  let initialIndex = allDivs.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    allDivs[i].style.zIndex = initialIndex--
  }
}
init();
```

You can also use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) if your init function is only used here.

```js
(() => {
  let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".pa");
  let initialIndex = allDivs.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    allDivs[i].style.zIndex = initialIndex--
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically what you need to change is the following:

1. Starting the loop from the length of your array,
2. Using `i--` to run it backwards,
3. Referencing the `div` element by `allDivs[i - 1]` because indexing starts from zero,
4. Adding value of `i` to `zIndex`.

Added extra logging to my solution just to see the values so I would somehow the following:

```js
const init = () => {
  let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".pa");

  for (let i = allDivs.length; i > 0; i--) {
    allDivs[i - 1].style.zIndex = i;
    console.log(allDivs[i - 1]);
  }
}
init();
```

```html
<div class="ma">
   <div class="pa">Test</div>
   <div class="pa">Test</div>
   <div class="pa">Test</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let init = () => {
  let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".pa");
  let initialIndex = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    allDivs[i].style.zIndex = allDivs.length - initialIndex++;
  }
}
init();
```

I used an expression, so that the higher the value of `i`, the lower the value of the `zIndex` would be. A more elegant, functional programming solution would be (see [forEach docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach))

```
let init = () => {
  const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".pa");
  allDivs.forEach((element, index) => element.style.zIndex = allDivs.length - index)l
}
init();
```

> I did try using -- so it would read allDivs[i].style.zIndex = initialIndex-- but this just took the z-index down 1,0,-1.

You were probably still starting with `let initialIndex = 1`. So your variable's values were 1, then 0, then -1, and it would have continued to -2, -3, etc. You most likely wanted to start at allDivs.length - index.